# Как разобраться что чему присваивать?

Tags: c#

Уже довольно давно, пользуюсь httpClient-ом как то так.

Просто где то взял ctrl+c / ctrl+v, или кто то подсказал, или на msdn.
Работает, отлично!

А тут решил разобраться и немного переделать под свои задачи ().

И никак не могу понять, как вы понимаете, что тому же `request.Content` - надо / можно присвоить `FormUrlEncodedContent` ?

Я проваливался в классы c помощью F12 в `HttpRequestMessage` и в `HttpContent`, но что то никакой ниточки не нашёл(

```
        using HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "https://***.ru");

        request.Headers.Add("Origin", "https://***ru");
        request.Headers.Add("Referer", "https://***.ru");

        // Передаваемые данные c POST запросом
        request.Content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[]
        {
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("key1", "value1"),
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("key2", "value2"),
        });
```

**UPD:**
Вопрос про - кому какой тип данных присвоить.

**@A K** - в первой части своего комментария правильно меня понял

Comment: Если я правильно понял вопрос, то в Visual Studio наведите курсор на request.Content, посмотрите тип и дальше пишите= new Этот тип. Об этом вопрос? Или о том, откуда взять key1 и key2? Они берутся когда смотришь конкретный сайт и видишь - ага, форма, ага, пост, ага, вот такие-то поля. Ну и фигачишь как есть. Никакой магии, главное матчасть надо знать. Потому что новички видят - запрос GET, но фигачат запрос POST'ом (или наоборот). Смешно? Ну или вот ещё: видно, что сайт передаёт формой - а они берут пример кода сo stackoverflow, в котором JSON в тело передаётся. Вот как так можно?

Comment: это зависит от того, что может принимать сервер, к которому направляется запрос. При этом устанавливается корректный Content-Type и тело запроса

Comment: @AK да, вы правильно поняли - первое! Но вот я навожу и даже проваливаюсь, мне не сказано что я такой то, такой то - принимаю FormUrlEncodedContent, я вот request.Headers, тоже может хотел бы какую то коллекцию присвоить xD

Comment: Тело запроса передаётся в функцию Send или SendЧтотоТам, которая отправляет запрос.

Comment: @nick_n_a, это кому был ответ? :-) Обрати внимание, что в вопросе речь про `HttpRequestMessage` - в котором как раз и есть все настройки запроса, включая тело, которое и хранится в поле `Content` :) `Send` вполне себе принимает тип `HttpRequestMessage`

Comment: @AK, в данном случае провалиться не выйдет, так как поле [`Content`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httprequestmessage.content?view=net-5.0#System_Net_Http_HttpRequestMessage_Content) имеет базовый тип [`HttpContent`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpcontent?view=net-5.0), который является абстрактным классом - а подставлять нужно конкретную реализацию: строку, stream, urlencoded и т.д.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Свойство `HttpRequestMessage.Content` имеет тип [`System.Net.Http.HttpContent`](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpcontent?view=net-5.0).  `HttpContent` - это абстрактный класс. Значит, свойству Content может быть присвоен объект любого класса, который наследует абстрактный класс `HttpContent`.

Чтобы узнать, каких стандартных наследников предлагает .NET "из-под капота" достаточно зайти в [документацию по свойству HttpRequestMessage.Content](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httprequestmessage.content?view=net-5.0):

- **ByteArrayContent** — Содержимое HTTP, основанное на массиве байтов.
- **FormUrlEncodedContent** — Содержимое HTTP кортежей имен и значений,
  закодированных с помощью типа MIME application/x-www-Form-UrlEncoded.
- **MultipartContent** — Содержимое HTTP, которое сериализуется с помощью
  спецификации multipart/* Content Type.
- **MultipartFormDataContent** — Содержимое HTTP, закодированное с помощью
  типа MIME multipart/form-data.
- **StreamContent** — Содержимое HTTP, основанное на потоке.
- **StringContent** — Содержимое HTTP, основанное на строке.

Comment: @nick_n_a мне показалось, что вопрос именно в том, как объяснить то, что свойству `Content` можно присвоить `FormUrlEncodedContent`. Если автор переформулирует вопрос либо напишет в комментариях, что ему нужно другое (например, как на конкретный сервер отправить конкретные данные), я, конечно, добавлю в свой ответ необходимую информацию

Comment: Хорошо, я понял)))

Comment: @AndreiKhotko вы правильно меня поняли xD - Спасибо! Я вроде и изучал ООП, но такие вещи всё равно до меня не дошли...

Comment: @Vipz Пожалуйста! Если ответ вас устраивает, можете поставить галочку слева от ответа